# How to assign Project to GHI or Hub (Github) Issue in CommandLine?

Tags: git, github, git-bash

My workflow is such, that I have a Project in Github.

In my VS Code, I use Hub to open a new Issue, at the time of opening, I can assign labels, however, there is no support for adding Project at the command line for hub.

I want to find a way to also assign Project value in the command line as my Project in Github has Automated Column TO DO (Kanban board) that if a new Issue is created, drops a card in this TO DO Column, and once I commit with reference to that Issue it moves it to Completed Column since that too is automated.

Is there any way I can add Project at the command line using GHI or Hub or any other tool?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Github hasn't exposed anything about Project in their Issue endpoint. 
https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/